# Capture mouse wheel with WPF webbrowser

Tags: webbrowser-control

I am using the WPF webbrowser displaying a canvas from which I can hook up mouse events in javascript to the DOM, except for mouse wheel events. As long as the mouse is over the webbrowser control no mouse events are detected from the outside either. Setting focus to DOM controls do not help either.
I am emulating Edge with meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge, charset=UTF-8'

What else is there to try ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution. Added Microsoft HTML from COM page to references. Added eventhandler for the webbrowser control wb and:

```
`private void wb1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event doc = ((mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)wb1.Document);
        doc.onmousewheel += (ev) => {
            dynamic d = ((dynamic)ev).wheelDelta; 
            return true;
        };  
`}
```

wheelDelta can now be injected to the DOM